# Create IR in BMC Remedy via PHP

Tags: web-services, remedy, websphere-process-server

I'm new in dealing connecting to a WebSphere Process Server application connecting to Web Services account, so I'm still learning.

I would like to create new Incident Requests in BMC Remedy Service Desk with 2 simple fields (Assigned User and Text in the body of the IR) from a Wordpress webform built on PHP and hosted by IIS server. I was told by the Remedy admin that using automated emails is not allowed to create new Incident Requests, but it might be possible to consume a web service (that is hosted by their WebSphere Process Server application) and he believes the Web Services are available using SOAP and REST as options.

Would this be the the best way to go? If not what would? Is there any tutorials or documentation on how to do this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following options:

- `PHP AR API`

  ```
  $Server = new ARAPI( "server", "user", "password" );
  $Values = $Server->createentry( "form", 2, 8 );
  ```
- `Driver Program` along with the command-line API, `CLI SAPI`

  ```
  php -r "exec('driver < my_driver_script.txt')"
  ```

**References**

- [PHP AR API](http://php-arapi.sourceforge.net/)
- [PHP CLI SAPI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)
- [AR System APIs Quick Start: Driver](https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-17515)
- [PHP at the core](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php)
- [Zend Extensions](https://wiki.php.net/internals/extensions)